# how to get coordinates of a polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: geometry, polygon, draw, openlayers

I have been looking for how to determine coordinates of the points which consist a polygon(feature) in OpenLayers.

Let's say I have created a polygon like the one in [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html) example. I need to know the points which consist the polygon, so I can save them somewhere.

I bet it is an easy one. I just couldn't find anything, probably I don't know what I should search for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Found it finally!](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.getVertices)

```
vectors.features[0].geometry.getVertices()
```

Comment: Where did you find the vectors object? Or where can I find it in the example.

Comment: Nevermind, I combined it with this example: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/intersects.html

Comment: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/intersects.html Updated link from @BartBug's comment